# Pandas NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

This is my problem: Cousera course on Apllied Data Science in Python I am doing Assigment 2.

Question 1
Which country has won the most gold medals in summer games?
This function should return a single string value.

This my code:

```
def answer_one():
  return df[df['Gold'] == df['Gold'].max()].index(0)
answer_one()
```

This is the error which I am getting:

```
NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

Comment: Please make sure your *whole post* is in English, you left some French in there. You appear to have forgotten to create a dataframe. **Elsewhere** in the tutorial something creates a dataframe and assigns it to `df`. Please do read your assignment carefully.

Comment: I think that the teachers should inform their students about the existence of www.stackoverflow.com at the **end** of the whole course, not at the very beginning. :(

Comment: @V.K.: I don't think that is called for. Asking questions is fine; what is lacking is knowing *how to ask good questions* (which Stack Overflow does try to teach, but many a new question asker ignores the [ask] information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, maybe your df object is not global variable. If so, you may pass df as an argument to the function.

For the syntax, your access to the index should be `.index[0]` rather than `.index(0)`.

A more compact solution is `return str(df['Gold'].idxmax())`.

Comment: better is `return df['Gold'].idxmax()`

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for suggestion. But I think the question asks to return string so I put a cast to string.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use .Hope so it will work

`return df['Gold'].idxmax()`